# How to call a function using node.js in my android application when data is added in firebase realtime database

Tags: java, node.js, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I have this project with two applications, an admin and a client application. This project is an SOS application, wherein the admin application is the response to the emergency, and the client application is the user requesting help. What I want to happen is that whenever a user request help(adds data on firebase real-time database), the cloud function will listen to that and calls the notification function in my admin application that will notify all the admin accounts.

Comment: It sounds like you want to [notify users when something interesting happens in the database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/use-cases#notify_users_when_something_interesting_happens), so I recommend checking out that section in the documentation.

Comment: Thank you I will check on that! @FrankvanPuffelen